# How to display all the slides in swiper js

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

```js
// Wheel animation
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  effect: "creative",
  // slidesPerView: 8,
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  visibilityFullFit: true,
  autoResize: false,
  // initialSlide: 6,
  loop: true,
  // loopedSlides: 6,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  grabCursor: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  creativeEffect: {
    perspective: true,
    limitProgress: 2,
    progressMultiplier: 1,
    prev: {
      translate: ["-70px", "10px", 0],
      rotate: [0, 0, -15],
      origin: "bottom",
      scale: 0.75,
      opacity: 0.5,
    },
    next: {
      translate: ["70px", "10px", 0],
      rotate: [0, 0, 15],
      origin: "bottom",
      scale: 0.75,
      opacity: 0.5,
    }
  },
});
```

```css
.wheel-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.wheel-level1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: #8C464E;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: #975F4B;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: #E3077E;
}

.box4 {
  background-color: #E30707;
}

.box5 {
  background-color: #FFAF9B;
}

.swiper-slide-active {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/8.4.3/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="wheel-container">
  <div class="wheel-level1">
    <!-- Slider main container -->
    <div class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide box1"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide box2"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide box3"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide box4"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide box5"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using swiper js library and want to show 3 slides in 90px height container and when container has height of 200px show 6 slides in swiper js.
Right now its show only 3 slides on any height, its not showing all the slides or specific slides.
Given below is the fiddle link for reference, can any know what is the issue?

https://jsfiddle.net/aqeelramay/vwxp3fcj/2/

Comment: I would use Jquery to detect the size of the container and then destroy and reinitialise the Swiper with a new slidesPerView value.